# Is it possible to show button press/select effect on Android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I can take action when a view (button) is clicked on home screen widget. The thing is, I also want to show an effect so user will feel that button is alive. (Like the blue glow when you press on start/stop button on Music Player widget.)

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what would be the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code for widget selector..

**buttonimg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
<item
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />
<item  
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
</selector>
```

**widget_layout.xml**

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/buttonimg"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="2px"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/button"
>
```